# application logins not saving = possible keychain issue

Tags: applications, password, keychain, login

(2015 iMac running Monterey 12.6.6)

I'm having login in issues with 2 3rd party desktop applications (both from the App store) that I believe are linked, possibly to a keychain issue?

Evernote desktop  - Application get stuck on the login splash window after I enter name/password.

1Password desktop - asks for 2FA pin every time I unlock the application.  After I enter it, it gives an error message "unable to save your 2FA token"

What I've tried - complete uninstall & reinstall of both applications, including multiple reboots of the machine.  Login in recovery mode followed by Disk First Aid and terminal command "fixHomePermissions".

I created a test account on the Mac and both applications seem to login just fine, so the problem seems to be limited to this main account on my Mac.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try next?  I'd hate to have to go through a huge migration to brand new account on the Mac for a relatively limited problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the associated keychain entries (save the passwords elsewhere, of course) then save them again as new.  Let me know if that works

Comment: I uninstalled both apps, rebooted, and deleted the keychain items that seemed to be linked to them.  That didn't fix the problem.

Comment: There’s probably a token of some kind cached that’s not being deleted.    Look for it in application caches.  It could be found in `~/Library/Applicaton Support/[app name]/`. Just focus on one app at a time so you can narrow things down as well.

Comment: Also, if you’re deleting the App, I would try something like [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) so it wipes out all of the “hidden” files associated with the app

Comment: 1Password support specifically told me not to use App Cleaner.  I deleted all the Application Support files for Evernote and deleted the application and restarted.  It let me log in the first time, but when I quit the application and  restarted it, it asked me for login information again and then got stuck as before.

Comment: Did 1Pass people say *why* not to use it?  Did they also have any insight why it works properly in a new account?  Is there anything *not* being loaded in the new acct. that is being loaded in your current acct?

Comment: According to 1Password support: "We never advise using an app cleaner with 1Password. They can become overly zealous and remove extra files and folders."  However, Evernote support specifically told me to use App Cleaner to remove and then reinstall the app.  Unfortunately, that did NOT fix the issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the following entry in the Console when either application has problems: "CSSM Exception: -2147413759 CSSMERR_DL_DATABASE_CORRUPT"   Does anyone know if that's related/helpful?